# Django: uploaded files lost when using inline formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.8

I need to add a simple messaging feature to a Django 1.8 application. I have a `Message` model and the following `Attachment` model:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    file = models.FileField()
```

It should be possible for a user to create a message with multiple attachments using this formset:

```
AttachmentFormset = inlineformset_factory(Message, Attachment, extra=1, exclude=[], can_delete=False)
```

This is how all the forms are rendered in my template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ msg_form.as_p }}

    {{ attachment_formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in attachment_formset.forms %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Send'%}"></input>
</form>
```

This is how I process the forms in my view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    msg_form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    attachment_formset = AttachmentFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    sender = request.user
    if msg_form.is_valid() and attachment_formset.is_valid():
        msg = msg_form.save(sender=sender)
        for aform in attachment_formset:
            a = aform.save(commit=False)
            a.message = msg
            a.save()
```

The problem is that somehow, `request.FILES` is always empty and the attachment form's `cleaned_data` is empty as well. What's happening to the uploaded file?! What's the correct way to process an inline formset with a  `FileField`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your form is missing the enctype

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```